# How to render an element in React which was created by createElement()?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, components, render

I have created an image element by using:

```
const image = document.createElement('image'); // or new Image();
```

How can I render this `image` variable in React ?

I don't want to use Html tags to do something like this:

```
<img src={image.src} ... />
```

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Well either create a `<div class="parent"> </div>` and then use

`document.querySelector(".parent").appendChild(imageElement)`

or simply,

`document.appendChild(imageElement)`

Comment: But I don't want to necessarily append it. I want to be able to render it wherever I want.

Comment: Then make it its own component @but-why

Comment: create a component and use it wherever you want. that's what React is all about. if not then use the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to go about doing this. You shouldn't directly manipulate the DOM with React. I would instead have an array of objects in your state, and in your component, map the objects to the elements of your choosing. Like this

```
const Component = () => {
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([{src:'path/to/src', alt:'altTag'}])
    return(
      <>
          {
          components.map(e => {
              return(<img src={require(e.src)} alt={e.alt} />)
          })
          }
      </>
      )
}
```

Wrote this from memory/without testing so there might be something wrong so dont kill me. But if you need to render it anywhere, make it its own component. If it's truly just one image, then you don't need the array/map just use an object and render it same way